# Why cert-manager overrides manually created certificate?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway, cert-manager

I'm creating a manual certificate in Kubernetes using akv2k8s(https://akv2k8s.io/). This gets a certificate from Azure Key Vault and creates a certificate in k8s. Below you can find the akv2k8s YAML file. I also have a cert-manager in my environment. Whenever I create a manual certificate, the cert-manager overrides and issues a new certificate. Then my manual certificate becomes a lets-encrypt certificate. But I don't want this to happen. Is there a way to prevent this?

**AKV2K8S Yaml**

```
apiVersion: spv.no/v1
kind: AzureKeyVaultSecret
metadata:
  name: manual-cert 
  namespace: default
spec:
  vault:
    name: keyvault-cert # name of key vault
    object:
      name: certname # name of the akv object
      type: certificate # akv object type
  output: 
    secret: 
      name: mysecret # kubernetes secret name
      type: kubernetes.io/tls # kubernetes secret type
```

[kubectl get certificaterequest output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwxyu.png)

**Ingress YAML Annotations Part**

I'm using Azure Application GW as Ingress Controller.

```
  annotations:
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: http
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/cookie-based-affinity: 'true'
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/request-timeout: '180'
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
    cert-manager.io/acme-challenge-type: http01
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
```

Comment: Did you find out what happened?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find the reason. As a workaround, I created another ingress for manual certificates. So far I had no problem.